# Display loading while retrieving data using Ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am using ajax, sometimes it takes time to load all the data from my database therefore I need to find a way to display (Loading...) While the data is not yet complete. Below is my sample code, and I am looking for some event while the data is still in process.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(data){
     $('#para').html(data);
   }
 });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple..

before you call the ajax start your loading image..& after the success hide the image
for eg :

```
$.fancybox.showLoading();
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(data){
     $.fancybox.hideLoading();
     $('#para').html(data);
   }
});
```

here

> $.fancybox.showLoading()

is my function in which I have the property of displaying the loader,

Answer (score 0):

This will be **internally called** whenever an ajax call is made.

```
$.ajaxStart(function() {
    $("img#loading").show();
});

$.ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("img#loading").hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="../images/loading.gif" alt="wait" id="loading"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="loading">LOADING...</div>

var loading = $("#loading");

loading.hide();

function doAjax() {
    loading.show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/js/beautifier.js",
        success: function (data) {
            loading.hide();
        }
    });
}

doAjax();
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/c6WGX/)